# How can I communicate over a PPP connection in a C# application?

Tags: c#, windows-7, ppp

I've used a PPP connection before using pppd in linux, but now I need to communicate with hardware via a PPP connection from a C# application and I'm new to .net. Is there a way I can open a PPP connection from within the application and set the baud rate, port and route some IP addresses to use the PPP connection? If this can't be done from within the application then I'd also like to know how those steps could be done in windows 7.

Comment: Whoa, PPP. I think I just had a flashback to 1994.

Answer (score 1):

Windows calls it "Dialup networking".  You are looking for the [rasdial](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa377004%28VS.85%29.aspx) function.

Answer (score 0):

This answer might help you out with configuring PPP in Windows 7.

https://stackoverflow.com/a/7085259/512910