# Creating a serial PPP connection between a Windows CE 6 device and Windows 7

Tags: windows, windows-7, serial-port, windows-ce, ppp

I need to create a PPP connection over a serial port between an embedded device running Windows CE 6 and a PC running Windows 7.

I've configured a dial-up modem on Windows 7 according to this: https://stackoverflow.com/a/7085259/512910

I used a terminal app on the CE device to confirm that attempting a connection sends the string "CLIENT".

I've also created a direct connection interface on the CE device, and used a terminal app to confirm that attempting a connection also sends the string "CLIENT" to the Windows 7 machine.

Unfortunately, neither side actually responds, and I'm not sure what the problem is.

What am I missing here? Is there a way to make either side listen for an incoming connection?

*-------------------------------- Edit 1/12/12 ----------------------------------*

I needed to add an incoming connection on the Windows 7 side. However, the connection doesn't appear to work, and times out after 90 seconds.

Here is my modem log.

```
01-09-2012 19:06:29.542 - Recv: CLIENT
01-09-2012 19:06:29.542 - Interpreted response: Ring
01-09-2012 19:06:29.542 - TSP Completing Async Operation(0x00010227) Status 0x00000000
01-09-2012 19:06:29.542 - TSP(0000): LINEEVENT: LINEDEVSTATE_RINGING(0x1)
01-09-2012 19:06:29.542 - TSP(0000): Answering Call
01-09-2012 19:06:29.542 - Answering the call.
01-09-2012 19:06:29.557 - Send: CLIENTSERVER
01-09-2012 19:06:29.557 - Connection established at 115200bps.
01-09-2012 19:06:29.557 - Error-control off or unknown.
01-09-2012 19:06:29.557 - Data compression off or unknown.
01-09-2012 19:06:29.557 - TSP Completing Async Operation(0x0001029e) Status 0x00000000
01-09-2012 19:06:29.557 - TSP(0000): LINEEVENT: LINECALLSTATE_CONNECTED
01-09-2012 19:06:59.572 - Read: Total: 388, Per/Sec: 12, Written: Total: 12, Per/Sec: 0
01-09-2012 19:08:30.208 - TSP(0000): Dropping Call
01-09-2012 19:08:30.208 - Hanging up the modem.
01-09-2012 19:08:30.208 - Hardware hangup by lowering DTR.
01-09-2012 19:08:30.208 - 115200,8,N,1, ctsfl=1, rtsctl=2
01-09-2012 19:08:30.208 - Initializing modem.
01-09-2012 19:08:30.208 - Waiting for a call.
01-09-2012 19:08:30.208 - TSP(0000): LINEEVENT: LINECALLSTATE_DISCONNECTED(0x1)
01-09-2012 19:08:30.208 - TSP(0000): LINEEVENT: LINECALLSTATE_IDLE
01-09-2012 19:08:30.208 - TSP Completing Async Operation(0x0001027c) Status 0x00000000
01-09-2012 19:08:30.208 - TSP(0000): Dropping Call
01-09-2012 19:08:30.208 - TSP Completing Async Operation(0x000101e3) Status 0x00000000
01-09-2012 19:08:30.208 - TSP(0000): Closing Call
```

Answer (score 1):

Here's a troubleshooting list I created back in 2002, but it should still be valid (#8 is likely not applicable, and some menus may have changed):

1. Make sure your cable is truly null modem. Your null modem cable must also be fully connected (CTS, RTS, DTR, DSR).
2. Click the ActiveSync icon on your PC and select Get Connected from the File menu. It should be actively scanning for your device when you run REPLLOG (the timing of getting both systems searching for each other is sometimes important).
3. Reset the CE device and follow the instructions from the beginning.
4. If REPLLOG doesn't connect within a few seconds of being run, tap the CANCEL button and retry.
5. If you get the "Verify COM Port Availability" dialog shortly after telling ActiveSync to Get Connected, you may not be connected to the right port of the CE device, or your cable may have a problem.
6. You can test the serial connection to your desktop PC by shutting down ActiveSync and running Hyperterminal at 19200,8N1. When you run REPLLOG, you should see "CLIENT" appear in the Hypterterminal window each of the four times the CE device tries to connect.
7. Verify that your device supports DTR or you have it shunted in the cable. PC ActiveSync application looks at DTR to determine if a device is connected.
8. A bug in some releases of CE reduce the number of chances you have to get connected. Consider loading a build created in June 2001 or later that adds DataSync components from Microsoft.
9. Make sure that ActiveSync has the communication protocol you are trying enabled. For example, if you are connecting with a null modem serail cable, make sure that ActiveSync has serial communications enabled. These settings are available through the ActiveSync interface under File | Connection Settings...

Comment: Thanks for your response. I did need to use a different cable because I didn't have one with DTR/DSR and CTS/RTS. Unfortunately, it's still not working.